# On Linux Solus Budgie, hibernate shuts down instead of hibernating

Tags: linux, hibernate, systemctl

I have 16GB RAM laptop equipped with an SSD drive with three partitions:

- a 20GB linux swap partition
- a bootable standard linux partition (hosting in my case Solus Budgie 4.0)
- a bootable standard windows partition (hosting Windows 10)

On Windows 10, I have no trouble hibernating and resuming -- everthing behaves as expected. On Linux, on the other hand, `systemctl hibernate` has my computer shut down instead of hibernating. Pressing the power button starts normally, with all previousely opened programs closed, and `who -b` showing a fresh boot.

How to proceed to diagnose and eventually fix this issue?

Comment: It's possible that it's just a Solus bug.  The Solus creator left, and some other developers have picked up the pieces.  It's a small team and they're working on it, but there are still loose ends.  Ubuntu Budgie is actually a much more polished and usable version, with functionality lacking in Solus.  It might be worth trying the Ubuntu version to see if that solves the issue (and you'll probably like it better, anyway).

Comment: All options are on the table, as the folks say, and changing distro is among them. But I still wanna give this one a chance, as it works really well for me overall. Assuming it's bug, any clue how I could disagnose the issue? Like suppose hibernation involves steps A+B+C on most Linux (GNOME-like) desktop environments. How may I look into these steps to find out where the bug occurs? I have in mind logs, files with default settings, etc.